# Employee name and salary using array

Tags: java

Create an array class for Employee which will reserved 7 elements. The class will have 2 data fields, a constructor and a get method for each field. The employee constructor requires two arguments: an employee number and a salary. You may use any looping statements.

I started it but I don't know how to finish it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee {
    int [] array= new int [8];
    private int empNum;
    private double empSal;
    void Test1(int e, double s){
        empNum = e;
        empSal = s;
    }

    public int getEmpNum(){
        return empNum;
    }
    public double getSalary(){
        return empSal;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Please enter your employee number:");
        int e = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Please enter your salary:");
        double s= sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: well, what do you want to do next ?

Comment: Maybe you _first_ should become clear about your task. E.g. I cannot see any constructor so far. Or your field `array`: what is the intention of this field? Why do you have a double `s` but call `nextInt()` on your scanner instance. What do you wan't to accomplish with your code in the first place?

Comment: aww it should be nextDouble, by the way i think i need to put this one : for (int counter = 1; counter< 8; counter++), my task is to create an array class which my output should be the employee name and their salary,

Comment: Sidenote: You should never use `double` for money, as it cannot accurately represent most decimal fractions. Use `BigDecimal` instead. Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ for details. It's not really important for training problems like this, but something you must understand before you ever write production software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you'll want 7 employees (at most), don't care for unique empNum (if you do you can add `equalsTo()` overriden function).
Also assuming you do all your additions once in the main function, with no special logic.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Employee {
    private int empNum;
    private double empSal;

    public Employee(int e, double s){
        empNum = e;
        empSal = s;
    }

    public int getEmpNum(){
        return empNum;
    }

    public double getSalary(){
        return empSal;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        List<Employee> employeeList= new ArrayList<Employee>();

        while (employeeList.size() < 7) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.printf("Please enter your employee number:");
            int e = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("Please enter your salary:");
            double s= sc.nextDouble();
            employeeList.add(new Employee(e, s));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigh... that problem statement is horrible. I think what it really wants to say is that you have to read a bunch of Employees from the command line and put them into an array. Like:

```
public class Employee {

    private int empNum;
    private double empSal;

    public Employee(int e, double s){
        empNum = e;
        empSal = s;
    }

    public int getEmpNum(){
        return empNum;
    }
    public double getSalary(){
        return empSal;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee[] array = new Employee[7];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Please enter your employee number:");
            int e = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("Please enter your salary:");
            double s = sc.nextDouble();
            array[i] = new Employee(e, s);
        }
    }
}
```